# Club Update query with group by based on two attributes //postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to update a table based on count which is derived by group by on two attributes?

Eg:
Thers a table having columns a,b,c

I need to update c based on count which has common(a,b)

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE in PostgreSQL has a [FROM extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-update.html) you could use:

```
update  YourTable as yt1
set     c = case when aggr.cnt > 5 then 'Q' else 'Z' end
from    (
        select  a
        ,       b
        ,       count(*) as cnt
        from    YourTable
        group by
                a
        ,       b
        ) as aggr
where   aggr.a = yt1.a
        and aggr.b = yt1.b
```